# How to extract the text between two spans with lxml (or BeautifulSoup)?

Tags: python, html, css, beautifulsoup, lxml

Given [this](http://www.flightclub.com/air-jordan-1-retro-high-og-unc-white-dk-powder-blue-012304) page, I'm looking to get out the value of Style ID:

[image]

I get the *Unique Selector* using the browser's developer tools:

```
li.attribute-list-item:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1)
```

so then with `urllib2` and `lxml`'s CSS capabilities:

```
import urllib2
from lxml import etree 
from lxml.cssselect import CSSSelector    
req = urllib2.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent' : "Magic Browser"}) 
con = urllib2.urlopen( req )
htmlparser = etree.HTMLParser()
tree = etree.parse(con, htmlparser)
x = CSSSelector('li.attribute-list-item:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1)')
```

If I then get the text value of the single element of x(tree):

[image]

It's giving me the text 'Style ID' rather than the actual value that follows it. Here's how it looks:

[image]

How do I get out the number (in this example, 555088 117)? I welcome `BeautifulSoup`-based suggestions as well.

**EDIT:** I'm specifically seeking CSS (class name or selector) based approaches.

Comment: If I highlight the number itself in Firebug or in the developer tools, neither give me any way to identify it (by CSS, XPath, or other)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**With `requests` + `lxml`**:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

response = requests.get("http://www.flightclub.com/air-jordan-1-retro-high-og-unc-white-dk-powder-blue-012304")
tree = html.fromstring(response.content)

style_id = tree.xpath('//ul[@class="mb-padding product-attribute-list"]/li[@class="attribute-list-item"][1]/text()[2]')[0].replace(',','').strip()
print style_id
```

**Output:**

```
555088 117
```

**Note:**

To avoid **`IndexError: list index out of range`** in case the site structure changes, you could replace:

```
style_id = tree.xpath('//ul[@class="mb-padding product-attribute-list"]/li[1]/text()[2]')[0].replace(',','').strip()
```

With:

```
style_id = ''.join(tree.xpath('//ul[@class="mb-padding product-attribute-list"]/li[1]/text()[2]')).replace(',','').strip()
```

Comment: Thanks. Because the element in question contains multiple parts, newlines, spaces etc. (as you've discovered) though, this is why I am seeking a more robust CSS selector-based approach.

Comment: My pleasure. I think this is the most accurate way to do it, since the full text is together and not divided by any node. I've updated `li[1]` to `li[@class="attribute-list-item"][1]` to be more specific.